# Based on month and year get the First day of the month and last day of month

Tags: datetime

I am new to extjs. i have month and year. i need 1st day of the month and last day of the month based on month and year

i know how to get 1st day and last day of the current month

```
  var date = new Date();
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

for example below i have month and year.. need to get first and last day of the month

```
var Month = 'March'
var Year = 2023
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getFirstDayOfMonth(year, month) {
  return new Date(year, month, 1);
}

const firstDayJanuary = getFirstDayOfMonth(2023, 0);
console.log('Full Date with First Day : '+firstDayJanuary);
console.log("First Day of January 2023 is - "+ firstDayJanuary.getDay());


function getLastDayOfMonth(year, month) {
  return new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
}

const lastDayJan = getLastDayOfMonth(2023, 0);
console.log('Full Date with last Day : '+lastDayJan);
console.log("Last Day of January 2023 is - "+ lastDayJan.getDay());
```

**Output :**

```
Full Date with First Day : Sun Jan 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
First Day of January 2023 is - 0   /*0 Indicate Sunday*/
Full Date with last Day : Tue Jan 31 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Last Day of January 2023 is - 2   /*2 Indicate Tuesday*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need date not like 0 or 1.  like this i need -> Sat May 06 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Comment: @NagRaju , Updated have a look again.